# Making android app with MIT App Inventor that shows data from arduino

Tags: android, arduino, app-inventor

I have connected my Arduino and Android phone with a Bluetooth module to display temperature that comes from Arduino with LM35 sensor on the Android.

The Android device can receive the data but it is showing several data at a certain time. So how can I program the Android app with **MIT App Inventor** so that it will show only one piece of data at a time and replace it when new data comes up?

Here is the App Inventor code and result:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV11L.png)
[image]
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsS9w.png)

[image]

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: Try adding some code, so shall your problem could be understood more properly.

Comment: I have added this

Comment: what about doing a search in the App Inventor forum [like this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/Arduino$20temperature%7Csort:relevance)?

Comment: So what can I do as solution?

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is making it so when ever your android receives data, It'll delete whatever data it's displaying currently, then display the new data. You also may need to increase the time interval on your timer.